# OpenCV warping from one triangle to another

Tags: opencv, image-processing, affinetransform

I would like to map one triangle inside an OpenCV Mat to another one, pretty much like warpAffine does (check it [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html)), but for triangles instead of quads, in order to use it in a Delaunay triangulation.

I know one is able to use a mask, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use the [getAffineTransform](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getaffine#getaffinetransform) to find the transform, and use warpAffine to apply it

Comment: Hi vasile, I would use getAffineTransform() and then warpAffine(), but warpAffine will transform the whole image. I just want one triangle to be transformed. It would be fine if I could set the ROI as a triangle, but I don't think this option exists.

Comment: You have to warp in a new image, and then copy with a mask. Or modify warpAffine to meet your needs

Comment: I believe the copy and mask should be fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

[image]
I have copied the above image and the following C++ code from my post [Warp one triangle to another using OpenCV ( C++ / Python )](http://www.learnopencv.com/warp-one-triangle-to-another-using-opencv-c-python/). The comments in the code below should provide a good idea what is going on. For more details and for python code you can visit the above link. All the pixels inside triangle tri1 in img1 are transformed to triangle tri2 in img2. Hope this helps.

```
void warpTriangle(Mat &img1, Mat &img2, vector<Point2f> tri1, vector<Point2f> tri2)
{
    // Find bounding rectangle for each triangle
    Rect r1 = boundingRect(tri1);
    Rect r2 = boundingRect(tri2);

   // Offset points by left top corner of the respective rectangles
   vector<Point2f> tri1Cropped, tri2Cropped;
   vector<Point> tri2CroppedInt;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      tri1Cropped.push_back( Point2f( tri1[i].x - r1.x, tri1[i].y -  r1.y) );
      tri2Cropped.push_back( Point2f( tri2[i].x - r2.x, tri2[i].y - r2.y) );

      // fillConvexPoly needs a vector of Point and not Point2f
      tri2CroppedInt.push_back( Point((int)(tri2[i].x - r2.x), (int)(tri2[i].y - r2.y)) );

   }

   // Apply warpImage to small rectangular patches
   Mat img1Cropped;
   img1(r1).copyTo(img1Cropped);

   // Given a pair of triangles, find the affine transform.
   Mat warpMat = getAffineTransform( tri1Cropped, tri2Cropped );

   // Apply the Affine Transform just found to the src image
   Mat img2Cropped = Mat::zeros(r2.height, r2.width, img1Cropped.type());
   warpAffine( img1Cropped, img2Cropped, warpMat, img2Cropped.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_REFLECT_101);

   // Get mask by filling triangle
   Mat mask = Mat::zeros(r2.height, r2.width, CV_32FC3);
   fillConvexPoly(mask, tri2CroppedInt, Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 16, 0);

  // Copy triangular region of the rectangular patch to the output image
  multiply(img2Cropped,mask, img2Cropped);
  multiply(img2(r2), Scalar(1.0,1.0,1.0) - mask, img2(r2));
  img2(r2) = img2(r2) + img2Cropped;

}
```